# How can I parameterize mgcv to return results like splines::ns()

Tags: r, spline

I am trying to convert some function in R. I would like to convert my `splines::ns()` functions to `mgcv`.

This is my example

```
min = 0
max = 10
tau = seq(min, max)
pDegree = 5
Q1 <- splines::ns(tau, pDegree)
Q2 <- mgcv::smoothCon(mgcv::s(tau, bs="cr", k=pDegree), data=data.frame(tau=tau))[[1]]$X
Q1
Q2
```

I want `Q1`, but the closest I have been able to get is `Q2`. I would like to make my code use `mgcv` alone, but I can't do that until `Q2` is the same as `Q1`

Thanks for the help.